# Alpha blending with two transparent textures not working correctly

Tags: ios, metal, alphablending

I have a destination texture:
[image]

Here the whole texture will be transparent (alpha = 0) except red color part. Red color will have alpha value of 0.5. I used a rectangle plane to present this texture.

Then i have this source texture. It is also a transparent texture with black color part. Black color will have alpha value of 0.5. I used another rectangle plane to present this texture and i change `MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor` blending to

```
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .one
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

Here blending works fine between two textures.

[image]

Then i try to merge these two textures into one destination texture. using `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`. My kernel function:

```
kernel void compute(
                    texture2d<float, access::read_write> des [[texture(0)]],
                    texture2d<float, access::read> src [[texture(1)]],
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    float4 srcColor = src.read(gid);
    float4 desColor = des.read(gid);
    float srcAlpha = srcColor.a;

    float4 outColor = srcColor  + desColor * (1 - srcAlpha);

    des.write(outColor, gid);
}
```

But after that blended color will be different than previous. Blending color is lighter than previous one.
[image]

How do I properly blend two transparent textures in kernel function? What is wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are using premultiplied alpha...

Try this instead (which is not premultiplied alpha):

```
float4 srcColor = src.read(gid);
float4 desColor = des.read(gid);

float4 outColor;
outColor.a = srcColor.a + desColor.a * (1f - srcColor.a);
if (outColor.a == 0f) {
  outColor.r = 0f;
  outColor.g = 0f;
  outColor.b = 0f;
} else {
  outColor.r = (srcColor.r * srcColor.a + desColor.r * desColor.a * (1f - srcColor.a)) / outColor.a;
  outColor.g = (srcColor.g * srcColor.a + desColor.g * desColor.a * (1f - srcColor.a)) / outColor.a;
  outColor.b = (srcColor.b * srcColor.a + desColor.b * desColor.a * (1f - srcColor.a)) / outColor.a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this one

Comment: I created another project and tried your solution. It worked fine. But not on my original project. There might be something wrong with my original project. Thank you by the way.